# Sending raw IP packets over UDP

Tags: udp, layer4

Can we send raw IP packets over UDP?

What are raw IP Packets?

UDP is a connectionless and unreliable protocol, is it?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am learning the protocols

Comment: I'd suggest reading a bit more about the [OSI Model](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/packet-traveling/osi-model/), and [how a packet travels across a network](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/packet-traveling/packet-traveling/). The two protocols operate at different layers: IP, a Layer 3 protocol, serves the purpose of end to end delivery, while UDP, a Layer 4 protocol, serves the purpose of service to service delivery. UDP can't get a packet to another host, nor can IP get a packet to an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP packets are layer 3.  UDP is layer 4.   That means that UDP packets are encapsulated *inside* IP packets, not the other way around.

Now, it is possible to tunnel IP packets, in which case you would have IP inside UDP inside another IP, but that is a special case.  For learning about the protocols, you can ignore that for now

Comment: So does it mean we can send raw IP packets over UDP ?

Comment: Technically, you can put anything you want in a UDP packet.  But to send UDP, you need to encapsulate it in IP, so it would be IP in UDP in IP.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Why do we need the upd then ?
Would it not have been enough to send the data using IP ?

Comment: I think you need to study the TCP/IP model a little more, specifically the transport layer.  Understand what functions it provides.  Yes, you can send information directly in IP, but you lose the functionality the the transport layer provides.

Comment: You can't send data as just "IP", IP (Layer 3) just allows for routing of packages in a network (a bit like addresses and zip codes on an envelope), you need UDP, TCP or some other Layer 4 protocol to handle the transmission of data. UDP basically just sends the data you want and hopes it gets there, while TCP has an elaborate process to ensure that every last bit you send using it gets there in the right order unmolested.

Comment: That's not quite correct.  You can put data directly in IP.  Many (now obsolete products) did just that.  IP has a payload and doesn't care what's in it.

Comment: Also, some well-known protocols, like OSPF, don't use tcp/udp.

Comment: @RonTrunk Didn't think of that, you're quite right!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  The question is what computer language do you intend on using?  There are traditional server-side languages such as Python as well as client side languages such as JavaScript.  There's also linux bash commands (available on Windows via cygwin).

```
sendip -p ipv4 -is 192.168.1.81 -p udp -us 5070 -ud 5060 -d "Hello" -v 192.168.1.81
```

See [Sending UDP packets from the command line](https://moythreads.com/wordpress/2012/03/15/sending-udp-packets-from-the-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called Foo over UDP on Linux.

- [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-gue.8.html)
- [paper](https://people.netfilter.org/pablo/netdev0.1/papers/UDP-Encapsulation-in-Linux.pdf)
- [lwn article](https://lwn.net/Articles/614348/)